# How to fetch data from Mysql database from any anchor tag using NodeJS. (Without using any form or a button basically)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am creating a node app with routes and auth in it, and just trying to retrieve data from a simple navbar anchor tag element. I am not able to trigger a function that is in controllers->auth.js.
Below is my file sequence-[File Sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYyrm.png)

My function in controllers->auth

```
exports.viewBookingsPat = (req,res) => {
// console.log(req.body);

// const { name, email, contact, plot, landmark, street, city } = req.body;

db.query('select * from booking where patient_id=?', [patientSess.ids], (error, results) => {
    
    console.log(results);

    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    if (results.length === 0) {
        return res.render('viewBookingsPat', {
            message: 'No Bookings Found',
            messageClass:'alert-warning'
        });
    }
    else{
        return res.render('viewBookingsPat',{bookingDetails:JSON.stringify(results)});
    }
});
```

}

I am trying to use this link in "href" in navbar-

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="/auth/viewBookingsPat">View Bookings</a>
      </li>
```

and trying to fetch all the booking data of the user.

Comment: Do you have `/auth/viewBookingsPat` route defined ?

Comment: Yes, I have.
Actually, I did it by making it as a form element/button and putting "/auth/viewBookingsPat" in the form 'action'. But I am still curious about doing this without using the form. Please tell.